# where is psinfo_t struct in linux library?

Tags: c, linux, redhat

i used "psinfo_t" struct for printing cpu usage, start time of the processes in Solaris. But our companie's server was moved to Linux(Red Hat Linux), so i can't compile my c code because it has psinfo_t struct. where can i find that?

Comment: The root of your problem is unlikely to be the structure itself, but rather the system library functions that produce and consume it.  If Linux has those or analogues of them then you should consult their Linux documentation.  Otherwise, you'll need an altogether different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Solaris ([`proc(5)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37852/proc-5.html)), `psinfo_t` is a type found in `<procfs.h>`.

This does not exist on Linux, and the two `/proc` filesystems have various differences.

Under Linux ([`proc(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), `/proc/[pid]/stat` contains the usual information found with [`ps(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html).

Here is the simplest of examples, printing information about the current process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *self = fopen("/proc/self/stat", "r");
    char buffer[512];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, self))
        printf("%s", buffer);

    fclose(self);
}
```